# Stream my code’s audio input and output through a phone call

Tags: python, audio, twilio, audio-streaming, twilio-api

Context: I want to create an audio-based game that is accessible through a phone call. The user should be able to call a number and talk to an AI/NPC while sound effects and music play in the background. I need to be able to layer audio on top of each other and stop some of them in real-time when the user says specific things (e.g. the user needs to be able to interrupt the speaker).

I thought Twilio could work, but after researching a lot it appears that their API doesn’t allow to play multiple audio files at the same time.

I could easily do that if the audio input/output were the speaker and microphone of my computer, but the user needs to be able to call a number on their phone and talk to it. So I thought that probably the best approach would be to simultaneously stream the input and output of the program through a phone call, but I have no idea how to do that.

How should I approach this problem? I would prefer to use Python, but I’m open to any ideas.

*Note: I am not providing any code because this is a high-level question seeking guidance about how to approach the problem.*

Comment: Twilio is the go-to for this, and can play streams.  You don't need/want their API to do your mixing.  That, you handle on your own in your application so that you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Wow, I didn’t know that. Can you tell me the name of the functionality I should learn more about to stream input and output at the same time?